# Is there an easy way to find the URL of client side rendered data?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, client-side

The only method I know to get the URL to client side rendered data is the following in chrome:

1. Go to 'Network' in the developer tools and filter for 'XHR'
2. Reload the page
3. Find the response containing the data
4. Go to 'Header'
5. Copy the 'Request URL'

Now this all works fine, but sometimes there are many XHR requests/responses and step 3 becomes non-trivial. It is not immediately obvious which one contains the data. Having to click every request and search for the data is quite time consuming.

Now the question becomes is there a way that is easier or faster?

---

To give an example: let's say I want to scrape the Fidelity mutual fund data. More specifically I am interested in the 3 year average annual return of these funds. Going through step 1 and 2 I end up with the situation in the image below.

[image: Example CSR scrape attempt]

However there are 57 XHR items and only the names and size to go on. I ended up searching the full response of all large responses for a specific fund's 3 year annual return (e.g. 27.34). But this is of course quite tedious. So is there a better way? Thanks in advance for your help